# an error in plone theming

Tags: themes, plone, diazo

I installed Plone 4.1.3 and I am trying to make a theme. I saw this link talk about this issue:

http://www.treebrolly.com/blog/turbo-plone-theming-with-xdv-diazo

and I followed the commands. When I run this command

```
$ ./bin/instance fg
```

it says

```
Error: error opening file /home/hosam/plone413/zinstance/parts/instance/etc/zope.conf: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/hosam/plone413/zinstance/parts/instance/etc/zope.conf'
For help, use ./bin/instance -h
hosam@hosam-desktop:~/plone413/zinstance$
```

I noticed that when I run this command

```
$ ./bin/buildout -c demo.cfg
```

this directory and its contents are deleted `/home/hosam/plone413/zinstance/parts/instance/`
and so this error appears to me, Any can help??

Answer (score 1):

When you run :

```
$ ./bin/buildout -c demo.cfg
```

the `parts` folder is supposed to be deleted and rebuilt (that's fine).
The error you are facing says that this command doesn't end correctly. Try to add the `-v` parameter

```
$ ./bin/buildout -v -c demo.cfg
```

so you will have a more verbose output and you can provide here a complete error traceback

Comment: Full traceback is indeed needed but I think the 'parts/' folder is only deleted by Plone 3.x buildouts.

Answer (score 1):

Set up your demo.cfg in a different buildout directory. Looking at the blog entry you mentioned, it's meant to standalone, not share the same buildout directory with a zope/plone instance.

You might want to consider using plone.app.theming instead of XDV. The big difference is that plone.app.theming runs inside Plone and doesn't require any separate build. That really simplifies things if you don't need to mix in content from non-Plone sources.